# How do i make a flat circle

Tags: modeling, unity

I need to make a flat circle as a floor for one of my objects, but I don't know how to make a circle.

I have tried different methods, but they don't work.

I have tried to make a mesh circle but nothing comes there, so can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way to create a circle (floor) is to add a circle object under *Add > Mesh > Circle*. Then <kbd>tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill in a face.

Comment: One last question is there any way to make it bigger on the z axis so it isnt flat but a little bit thicker?

Comment: yeah ! go to edit mode and select the top face of the plane ,E to extrude and z to z axis ( but u should make sure that the plane is facing z axis ) , and extrude as ur wish :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add mesh circle, set the faces from *ngon* to *triangles*. Also make sure that you are *NOT* in wireframe. The circle should show in viewport + final render *+* viewport render. If it does not, **please tell me**! I would be happy to help further.
Here's a picture of setting this:
Before:[image]  After [image]

Here are pictures of the *circle* before and after:
[image]

After:
[image]

Comment: I am so new to blender that I don't know where that "faces" is can you maybe take a screenshot and show me?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to create a circular plane with (sort of) uniform vertices.

This may be useful in case you are not satisfied with either the "triangle fan" mesh generated by Add -> Mesh -> Circle -> (Fill option) or the "zigzag" mesh generated by Mesh Circle -> (Edit Mode) -> Face fill

1. Add -> Mesh -> Plane
2. Add -> Mesh -> Cylinder
3. Move them to intersect
4. Boolean difference modifier on the Plane, choose Cylinder as operand object
5. Apply modifier

**The result:**
[image]

Comment: particularly useful for eg. Cloth simulations